# Title on only first page

Tags: sas

This is my first time using a programming related stack. So if this doesn't belong or should go somewhere please inform me and I will fix it.

I've just begun to use SAS Studio. I believe I have set up a title correctly, but I can't seem to get it only on the first page. It adds the title to every subsequent page I create. I've just begun watching tutorials on the SAS website, but I have yet to run across the answer to this particular question. Can anyone help point me in a correct direction?

Here is my code:

```
Data Question21;
Input Transfers Broken @@;
Datalines;
1 16 0 9 2 17 0 12 3 22 1 13 0 8 1 15 2 19 0 11
;

title color=red Bold underlin=3 "Assignment #1";

Proc Print;
run;

Proc sgplot;
scatter x=Transfers y=Broken;
run;

Proc reg;
model Broken=Transfers;
run;
```

and this is a sample of what happens when it runs:[image: Output Data]

Comment: This question is fine here.  The general rule with [tag:SAS] questions is if they're about "how to do something [programming-wise] in SAS", they go here.  If they're about statistics, ie something you'd go to your stat professor to ask and might have the same answer in [tag:r] or similar, then they go on [stats.se].  If they're about statistics AND programming in SAS, they can go in either place (put them where you prefer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`TITLE`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000220968.htm) is a global statement, and will take effect until you turn it off.  So the simple answer is: after the PROC in which you want the title, and its `RUN` statement (or `QUIT` in those that use quit), enter

```
title;
```

Which will then clear all titles.

In a bit more detail:

Titles, and Footnotes, have a set of ten (each) that are in a sort of 'stack' (Setting one removes all higher ones).  SAS stores them internally, and any time a `PROC` or anything else runs that supports a title, it will grab whatever is currently in the title and footnote stacks and show those titles and those footnotes.

It is important to remember that any `PROC` or `DATA` step doesn't submit fully until `RUN` or `QUIT` is reached, or else another `PROC` or `DATA` step is begun (called a "Step Boundary").  Since `TITLE` is a global statement, what'll happen is whatever is in the current title stack *when the step boundary is reached* will be shown.  Notice what you actually see here...

```
title "One Title";
proc print data=sashelp.class;
title "Two Title";
run;
title "Three Title";
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
tables sex*age/list;
run;
title "Four";
```

A good habit is to always put `TITLE` statements in a consistent place - some disagree over *where*, but choose either:

- Before the `PROC`/`DATA` statement
- Immediately before `RUN`

and stick with it.  Then, after every `RUN`, include a `TITLE;`, unless you intentionally have a common title.

For example, I might have an assignment that is to print `SASHELP.CLASS`, run some frequencies on it, and use `PROC UNIVARIATE` to look at the `WEIGHT` and `HEIGHT` variables.

```
title "SAS Class, Assignment One";
title2 "Written By Joe, 9/2/2015";  *these are global titles used for all printing;

title3 "Print of first 10 obs of SASHELP.CLASS";
proc print data=sashelp.class(obs=10);
run;
title3;

title3 "Freq of AGE, SEX in SASHELP.CLASS";
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
  tables age sex;
run;
title3;

title3 "Univariate Examination of SASHELP.CLASS";

title4 "HEIGHT variable";
proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
  var height;
run;
title4;

title4 "WEIGHT variable";
proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
  var weight;
run;
title3; *notice 3 here - ending all of 3;

title3 "Plot of SASHELP.CLASS Height v Weight";
proc sgplot data=sashelp.class;
  scatter x=weight y=height;
run;

title; *ends all titles!;
```